# How long does a DMARC record take to be recognized?

Tags: dmarc

I created a DMARC record for a domain about 20 hours ago but it is not yet recognized.
How long does a DMARC record take to be recognized?

Comment: Since it is basically a DNS record, I would say pretty quick (for a new record). Where are you checking? What makes you say it is 'not recognized'? Is the syntax correct? Please share some more details, preferably the contents of the TXT record.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I already found the solution to the problem, I just posted it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that for many DNS hosting providers, you will only type "_DMARC" as the host / name and the tool will add your domain name automatically.

I had written "_DMARC.mydomain.com" instead only "_DMARC" which generated the wrong host / name _DMARC.mydomain.com.mydomain.com